# Change format of attribute in serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, postgis

I'm using [PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) for GIS operations and types on PostgreSQL. In table `elements` I have attribute `:coordinates` type `geometry`. In ruby I can do coordinates.x and it returns x coordinate. But how can I parse this in serializer?

```
class ElementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :coordinates
end
```

In development returns:

```
"POINT (45.815927 16.00538)"
```

In production returns:

```
0101000000581CCEFC6AE8464003E962D34A013040
```

I want something like:

```
class ElementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes {:coordinates => [:coordinates.x, :coordinates.y]}
end
```

Want to return:
`[45.815927 16.00538]`

Comment: do you have more than one version of the gem installed?

Comment: no, only `# postGIS
gem 'rgeo'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'rgeo-proj4'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why in development environment the serializer returns something different than in production, but when it comes to your main issue you can execute code like `coordinates.x` inside ActiveModelSerializer - you just need to call it through `object` instance variable, so something like code below should work in your case:

```
class ElementSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :coordinates

  def coordinates
    [object.coordinates.x, object.coordinates.y]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Can I do that for nested objects?

Comment: `object` contains your original ApplicationRecord class object, so you should be able to call any methods or attribute from it. If by `nested objects` you mean associations then yes, you can you it - same like in other parts of your program. 

But be aware of potential performance issues (google `n+1 query`) and load those associations beforehand (using `include`).

Comment: Element is having many measurements. So I was thinking something like this in element serializer: `attribute :measurements, each_serializer: MeasurementSerializer`.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. I have also coordinates in measurements. (array of measuremnts) which is in element.

Comment: I handle it like this: `has_many :measurements, serializer: MeasurementSerializer`. thanks for help